# ASP.NET MVC 5, Web Api 2 - PasswordValidator not executing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have added a `Web Api` project to my VS2015 solution, and I'm trying to disable some of those password requirements.

For example, I would get this error when accessing the `Register()` method via Fiddler POST request:

```
 Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character.
```

I've added `manager.UserValidator` and `manager.PasswordValidator` in `IdentityConfig.cs`, but it's not getting hit.

Here is my `IdentityConfig.cs` file:

```js
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;

namespace WorkbenchAPI.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
            // Add custom user claims here

            // added additional validators - 03/11/2016 BM:
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
                RequireDigit = false,
                RequireLowercase = false,
                RequireUppercase = false,
            };

            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }
        
        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

`AccountController.cs` is standard here. Again, I've added a `Web Api` project so these controllers get generated.

Here is a snippet of AccountController.cs, showing the `Register()` method:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using WorkbenchAPI.Models;
using WorkbenchAPI.Providers;
using WorkbenchAPI.Results;

namespace WorkbenchAPI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
    public class AccountController : ApiController
    {
        private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
        
        public AccountController()
        {
        }

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
            ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;            
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }
      
      
        // POST api/Account/Register
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("Register")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return GetErrorResult(result);
            }

            return Ok();
        }


  }
}
```

And here's a snippet from `AccountBindingModel' :

```js
    public class RegisterBindingModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Updated `IdentityConfig.cs`

```js
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;

namespace WorkbenchAPI.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
            // Add custom user claims here

            // added additional validators - 03/11/2016 BM:
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
                RequireDigit = false,
                RequireLowercase = false,
                RequireUppercase = false,
            };

            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager()
             : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(ApplicationDbContext.Create()))
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            // added additional validators - 03/11/2016 BM:
            this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords here
            this.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
                RequireDigit = false,
                RequireLowercase = false,
                RequireUppercase = false,
            };
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }
        
        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the `RegisterBindingModel` class

Comment: @Jasen - done. please see post. I was looking at that before, but unclear on what attrib's to add.

Answer (score 0):

Those configurations need to go into the initialization of the `ApplicationUserManager` not in the `ApplicationUser`.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser> {

    public ApplicationUserManager()
            : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(ApplicationDbContext.Create())) {
            Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize() {
        // added additional validators - 03/11/2016 BM:
        this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords here
        this.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought so, but it's still not getting hit. I'll post updated code now.

Comment: What is not getting hit?

Comment: @Nikos - well, I put a break point in there and ran a debug instance of my Web Api project, thinking I would hit your `initialize` method

Comment: Put a break point into the constructor of your controller and see if the Usermanager is being resolved/injected into it. If it isn't then the frame work does not know how to resolve it.

Comment: Just for testing purposes new up an instance of the UserManager manually in the constructor to make sure Identity works. Then you can start looking into the other problem of why DI isn't working

Comment: I will thx. It worked in the std MVC project this way, btw. Same code.